# Getting error when I am trying to add a new List object to a pre-defined List object

Tags: java, list, java-8, unsupportedoperation

> I am working on Spring Boot version 2, using Java 8 and when I am trying to add a new List object to a pre-defined List object(i.e topicList) in the "createTopic" method I'm getting an error.

**

> TopicService.java

**

```
public class TopicService {

    private List<TopicObject>  topicList = Arrays.asList(
            new TopicObject("Java", "Java Course", "Spring boot in java"),
            new TopicObject("Maths", "Mathematics class","12th maths")
    );



    public String createTopic(TopicObject topicObj){

         topicList.add(new TopicObject("Java1", "Java Course1", "Spring boot in java1"));

        return "Request successful"  ;
    }
}
```

**

> TopicObject.java

**

```
package io.javabrains.springBootStarter.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class TopicObject {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    public TopicObject() {
    }

    public TopicObject(String id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

**

> Error

**

> 2020-04-15 19:52:27.172 ERROR 15312 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null     at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_221]     at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_221]     at
>   io.javabrains.springBootStarter.Service.TopicService.createTopic(TopicService.java:29)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   io.javabrains.springBootStarter.controller.TopicController.createTopic(TopicController.java:31)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]

**>I don't know if a new object can be added to the "topicList" in this way. Can someone help?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asLit` retuns an unmodifiable `List` object. If you intend to add elements to it you need to use a modifiable `List` type, such as an `ArrayList`:

```java
private List<TopicObject>  topicList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new TopicObject("Java", "Java Course", "Spring boot in java"),
        new TopicObject("Maths", "Mathematics class", "12th maths")
));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` won't support new element addition. So initialize new ArrayList and add new elements. So instead of

```
private List<TopicObject>  topicList = Arrays.asList(
            new TopicObject("Java", "Java Course", "Spring boot in java"),
            new TopicObject("Maths", "Mathematics class","12th maths")
    );
```

change to

```
private List<TopicObject>  topicList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new TopicObject("Java", "Java Course", "Spring boot in java"),
        new TopicObject("Maths", "Mathematics class", "12th maths")
));
```